# What is this shrub with small red flowers, found in St. Lucia?

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

I photographed this unusual shrub in November, in St. Lucia, but haven't been able to identify it. It had small (1-2cm), red flowers, growing out of pink-ish sepals in many elongate clusters as shown below (click for larger view):

[image: Flower 1]
[image: Flower 2]
[image: Flower 3]

Can anyone identify this plant, or at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [clerodendrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerodendrum) [thomsoniae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerodendrum_thomsoniae) or a similar looking cultivar also called the bleeding heart vine.  The genus is found in many tropical areas: Asia, Africa, Australasia and tropical Americas.

It is a weak climber but can be trained into a pillar or grown as a shrub.  It does not tolerate frost but in some tropical regions is vigorous enough to have escaped cultivation and become naturalized.

When I grew this plant it was quite happy in a 12 inch pot with lots of diffuse light and water.  If grown in a pot this plant gives best performance with flowering plant fertilizer added in the blooming season.